# Loading vars for php and bash in same config file

Tags: php, bash

I am making a small app, and it would be nice if the config file could be in common for bash and php.
So far I got at :

```
<<COMMENT
<?php
$dbuser = "Hello world!";
$dbpass = "testpass";
echo "$dbuser";
/*
COMMENT
dbuser="Hello world";
dbpass="testpass";
echo $dbuser;
<<COMMENT
*/
?>
COMMENT
```

and almost works as desired:

```
jupiter@jupi:~/$ ./conf.sh.php 
Hello world
jupiter@jupi:~/$ php conf.sh.php 
<<COMMENT
Hello world!COMMENT
```

1. I need to remove the COMMENTS that appear in php
2. It would be awesome if someone knew a way to declare vars only only once for both languages!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why? Choose a language and use it. What purpose is there in having this kind of hybrid file? You just end up writing everything twice. Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: Use php to load the configuration file used by bash script.

Comment: in 95% of the cases, I expect php not to be available on the machine - bash is used to generate static html site.  
in the 5% of the cases where php would be available, I'll write a few pages that will make static generation unnesecary.   
In both cases user will end up with a html gallery to see. 
I know it's unnecessarily complicated, but for the sake of the challenge I'm trying to get one script that runs similarly in both languages.  It just needs to be sourced from external files for loading db credentials, will not echo nor do anything else.

Comment: Just write two scripts, with some instructions for what to do if you have PHP, and what to do if you don't. Then you don't have to worry about seeing text from the other language by accident, and it'll make your code a lot easier for you to write and maintain as well

Comment: That works and is easier to maintain indeed, but I'd really prefer having the same script running both languages just for the sake of it!
```dbuser="Hello world!";
dbpass="testpass";
[ "php --version" ] && echo -e '<?php'"\n"'$dbuser = '"\"$dbuser\";\n"'$dbpass = '"\"$dbpass\";\n"'?>'>tardisconf.php```

Comment: Suit yourself but that's a horrible nightmare of a codebase. There are going to be times I think where it's unavoidable to end up seeing artefacts from the other language on screen. And there's no way to share any variables between them, so you gain nothing and lose a lot.

Comment: I have to agree. This is not a good idea at all. You're already running into issues just trying to execute a few, simple variables. This is going to be an uphill battle all the way and you'll end up with spaghetti code galore.

Comment: I understand your concerns, but it is not like that code will evolve any time - at all - ever.
Got rid of the second extra line, only one to go!  Once I get rid of it, it will be good for eternity... hence I don't care about maintainability.
As code is sources in bash, allows for return hence skipping the rest of php code!
```
#!/bin/bash
<<a
<?php
$sqldb = "one";
$sqluser = "two";
$sqlpass = "three";
/*
a
sqldb="one"
sqluser="two"
sqlpass="three"
return 0
*/
?>
```
If I just load the page from another php page, can I get rid of that <<a on final display ?

Comment: "is not like that code will evolve any time - at all - ever".... famous last words. from quite a lot of experience now, I can say that the number of times I've "finished" some code and it has then stayed in that state permanently must be less than a dozen. And I've written **a lot** of code. But again, it's ultimately your choice, do whatever you think is best, but don't be surprised if, should you post another question about this code in future, you get a whole load of "wtf" comments and not a lot of quick solutions.

Comment: Again, I know it is a bad practice - that is not the question.
It is not production code, it is a proof of concept.  I did stuff in bf and intercal, it was insightful, not efficient.
The question is "is it possible" or put in another way "does anyone have the skills to make that code run without that noise".

Comment: I just found out this kind of programs is called a polyglot!

Comment: I had something like that for a script that required a CMD (Windows), a PowerShell, a bash and a Python version.  I use a simple INI file.  `[section]` and `var = value`.  Then parsed it.  PowerShell and Python both have INI parsers.  For CMD and bash, I wrote one.  I did not allow variables in other variables like a real INI would, no need for me and makes it easier.

Comment: Why not use `.env` files for this?

Comment: I just needed to load 3 variables, want to avoid adding another layer of parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a couple of ways around it; here are the solutions code:

1. The first solution is a polyglot script polyconf.sh.php

   ```
   <<a
   <?php
   $sqldb = "dbname";
   $sqluser = "username";
   $sqlpass = "pass";
   /*
   a
   sqldb="dbname"
   sqluser="username"
   sqlpass="pass"
   return 0
   */
   ?>
   ```

- The trick to get it to work is how you call the script:

  - in bash: source polyconf.sh.php from another file (as ./polyconf.sh.php errors on return)
  - in php: include it from another page between html comments, as in

    ```
    <?php
    echo "<!--\n";
    include 'tardisconf.sh.php';
    echo "-->\n";
    echo $sqlpass;
    ?>
    ```

As pointed out by @Adyson "Suit yourself but that's a horrible nightmare of a codebase" - this is indeed, but it works and I am happy to have a working polyglot.

2. The second solution is not a polyglot, but a more maintainable bash conf that generates a php config out of itself:

   ```
   sqldb="dbname";
   sqluser="username";
   sqlpass="pass";
   cat "$0"|grep -v grep|sed -e 's/^/$/g' -e 's/=/ = /g' > settings.php
   ```